# Svn with Zend Studio 8

Tags: svn, zend-studio

In PhpEd I would press Ctrl + W to bring up my project file explorer pane, press Home key to go to the root, then Ctrl + ContextMenu key to open the Windows Explorer shell menu. From there I could easily press U or C to update or commit using Svn Tortoise.

I'd like something equally smooth and easy to issue Svn commands from ZS. I'm open to any solution, not necessarily involving Svn Tortoise, even though I really like Tortoise :-)